# Use dynamic alias in Python Django when switching from Debug to Production

Tags: python, django, url, alias, django-settings

I have the following http address when running in development (manage.py runserver)

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

When using wamp i use an alias named picon

```
http://localhost/picon/
```

When clicking on links from the nav bar the navigation works fine for both deployments. But when i click from the following views.py the urls break;

```
def addcustomer(request):      
    form = AddCustomerForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        save_it = form.save(commit=False)
        save_it.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Customer added succesfully')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/picon/customers')

    return render_to_response("addcustomer.html",
                              locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In the production server i use the prefix /picon/ because otherwise the link can not be found when using an alias. Off course this alias is not available on the development version.

So my question, can i create a dynamic alias that has a relation to the debug status in the settings.py file.

for example;

```
If Debug:
    alias = ''
else:
    alias = 'picon/'
```

if this is possible, how would i then reference to the alias in the views.py using the following line;

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/picon/customers')
```

Edit: added my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'signups.views.home', name='home'),

    url(r'^thank-you/$', 'signups.views.thankyou', name='thankyou'),
    url(r'^about-us/$', 'signups.views.aboutus', name='aboutus'),

    url(r'^customers/$', 'formlist.views.customers', name='customers'),
    url(r'^addcustomer/$', 'formlist.views.addcustomer', name='addcustomer'),

    #url(r'^addcustomer_res/$', 'formlist.views.addcustomer', name='addcustomer'),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: How does your `urls.py` look? Thanks.

Comment: I have added the urls.py to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly why you should not hard-code URLs in views or templates. Use `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` - or the `{% url %}` template tag - to calculate the URL dynamically, including any prefix.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('customers'))
```

where 'customers' is the `name` value from the URLconf.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the urls from another file, dynamically:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

#PAY ATTENTION HERE
from another_location import urls as another_urls

admin.autodiscover()

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = url(r'^picon/', include(another_urls))
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
else:
    urlpatterns = url(r'^', include(another_urls))
```

Having your `another_location.urls` file like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'signups.views.home', name='home'),

    url(r'^thank-you/$', 'signups.views.thankyou', name='thankyou'),
    url(r'^about-us/$', 'signups.views.aboutus', name='aboutus'),

    url(r'^customers/$', 'formlist.views.customers', name='customers'),
    url(r'^addcustomer/$', 'formlist.views.addcustomer', name='addcustomer'),

    #url(r'^addcustomer_res/$', 'formlist.views.addcustomer', name='addcustomer'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

You must ensure such file is pythonpath-reachable via imports.

**Edit**: also, don't hardcode URLS. **Always** use `reverse`. It will be harmless to you since you gave names for each of your urls (`reverse('customers')` will give you the right url no matter where is it deployed).